# Error cross compiling vlc Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) 64 to win 64

Tags: compiler-errors, mingw, vlc, cross-compiling

I have had several attempts following [the](http://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile) procedure at official video lan wiki

using the host: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Earlier, configure script was giving errors for libgcrypt, but disabling it proceeded to successful config.

Compilation fails because it does not find `__ms_vsnprintf'.

Following is a sample compilation error log.

```
../vlc-2.0.4cross/contrib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libvpx.a(onyx_if.c.o):(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
../vlc-2.0.4cross/contrib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libvpx.a(bitstream.c.o):(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
../vlc-2.0.4cross/contrib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libvpx.a(ethreading.c.o):(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
../vlc-2.0.4cross/contrib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libvpx.a(boolhuff.c.o):(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
../vlc-2.0.4cross/contrib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libvpx.a(encodemv.c.o):(.text+0x336): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
```

I can't seem to get around with this error. Have already tried disabling relevant component such as

> --disable-libcddb --disable-cdda

in the configure script. But the same error pops up in another place. Would really appreciate any pointers.

**Update:** VLC forums indicated that qt4 needs to be recompiled and i did that successfully. Have also tried both win64 and win32 targets. But the result is same above compilation error. I have tried vlc source version 2.0.4 and 2.0.5. Going to try from git 2.1.0 with qt 4.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found several issues primary of which was that mingw-x64 version 3 (which at the time of this writing is experimental package) is required. It is not available on debian or ubuntu resources so [package](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/mingw-w64-i686-dev) needs to be downloaded or install directly from source.

The [following](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=106846) instructions worked for me on both ubuntu 12.04 as well as mint 12, with the exception that if you want the final windows package to be generated as an installer, you need vlc code from git repo (version 2.1.0 at least). As of this writing both vlc 2.0.4 and 2.0.5 tar balls had some issue with generating the installer.

See the following [thread](http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2012-December/091031.html) from vlc dev mailing list